# powershell change AD user attribute

Tags: powershell

I need to search through all users in AD, find their attribute "mail" and in this attribute replace @hell.com to @heaven.com

I'm stuck at exporting and importing to csv...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
get-aduser -Filter {samaccountname -like "gmaleev"} -properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName,mail | export-csv -NoTypeInformation d:\1.csv
$impfile = "d:\1.csv"
Import-CSV $impFile
foreach ($user in $users)
{
$sam = $user.samaccountname
$email = $user.mail
write-host "User $sam has mail $mail"
}
```

It doesn't work, why?

Comment: The import and ForEach are not connected you should have `Import-CSV $impFile | foreach ($user in $users)` Currently you import the data to output and it is not processed by foreach

Answer (score 0):

The current issue is that you are running a cmdlet to import the data but not saving it. Your `ForEach` cmdlet is not processing any data so you should have blank output except that of `Import-CSV` which should be outputing to console.

Also it seems redundant to export the data to import it again. I will presume that you have a reason for exporting it.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$impfile = "d:\1.csv"
$results = Get-AdUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "gmaleev"} -properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName,mail 
$results | export-csv -NoTypeInformation d:\1.csv
$results | foreach ($user in $users){
    $sam = $user.samaccountname
    $email = $user.mail
    write-host "User $sam has mail $mail"
}
```

This should address what you are showing. It will get the same data and save it to the variable `$results`. Export that data and then piping it to the `ForEach` to process

Your title suggets that you want to change user attributes. To do that you would need to use `Set-Aduser`. Depending on what your environment is this might not be the best way to manipulate email attributes.